# Google Cloud w/ Ansible Dynamic Inventory Problems

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ansible-inventory

I'm hoping the community can help with the issue I'm experiencing.  I'm attempting to setup a dynamic inventory using this doc:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html

So far I'm not having any success as it seems that each error leads to another down the rabbit hole I go....

```
Error:
~/ansible/inventory$ ./gce.py --list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gce.py", line 484, in <module>
    GceInventory()
  File "./gce.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.driver = self.get_gce_driver()
  File "./gce.py", line 304, in get_gce_driver
    gce = get_driver(Provider.GCE)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 1058, in __init__
    self.zone_list = self.ex_list_zones()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 1790, in ex_list_zones
    response = self.connection.request(request, method='GET').object
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 120, in request
    response = super(GCEConnection, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 718, in request
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 797, in request
    response = responseCls(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.object = self.parse_body()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 287, in parse_body
    raise GoogleBaseError(message, self.status, code)
libcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: {'domain': 'global', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}
```

I don't understand why there is insufficient permissions.  I've created a service account which I initialized in the instance and I can successful use the gcloud cli.

```
Example:
~/ansible/inventory$ gcloud auth list
Credentialed Accounts:
 - REDA...@developer.gserviceaccount.com
 - b*******@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com ACTIVE
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

~/ansible/inventory$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME     ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
jump      us-east1-b  f1-micro                   10.142.0.2     REDACTED     RUNNING
inst1     us-east1-b  f1-micro                   10.142.0.3                  RUNNING
inst2     us-east1-b  f1-micro                   10.142.0.4                  RUNNING
inst3     us-east1-b  f1-micro                   10.142.0.5                  RUNNING


~/ansible/inventory$ cat secrets.py
GCE_PARAMS = ('', '')
GCE_KEYWORD_PARAMS = {'project': 'REDACTED', 'datacenter': 'us-east1-b'}
```

The docs says you can leave the GCE_PARAMS blank if you are doing this from an instance within the project.  I've tried both ways and I can't get past this permissions issue.  I've made the service account owner and it hasn't helped.

```
~/ansible/inventory$ cat gce.ini
[gce]
libcloud_secrets = /home/REDACTED/ansible/inventory/secrets.py

# If you are not going to use a 'secrets.py' file, you can set the necessary
# authorization parameters here.
#gce_service_account_email_address = b*******@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com
#gce_service_account_pem_file_path = /home/REDACTED/S********************a.json
#gce_project_id = "REDACTED"
#gce_zone = https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/REDACTED/zones/us-east1-b
```

Note:  The above parameters are commented out because I am using secrets.py.  I've tried with just these values alone and commenting out the "libcloud_secrets" but that didn't help.

```
~/ansible/inventory$ echo $GCE_INI_PATH
/home/REDACTED/ansible/inventory/gce.ini   <---tried both with only the path and also the filename and same result
```

Is there are definitive guide posted by Google on the exact steps to make this work?  A dynamic inventory isn't mission critical but it would certainly make life easier down the road when I start automating instance deployment.  It seems like this is taking too much effort to get right and there has to be a simple way to make this work.  Between this ansible doc and the commented info in the gce.ini there is conflicting info.

For craps and giggles I used this openssl command to convert a newly created key for the same service account to *.pem.  I then entered this info into the secrets.py and attempted to run the ./gce.py --list again and it still failed.  Same error.  Sigh....

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pkey.pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -nodes -nocerts | openssl rsa -out pkey.pem

~/ansible/inventory$ cat secrets.py
GCE_PARAMS = ('b*******@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com', '/home/REDACTED/servkey.pem')
GCE_KEYWORD_PARAMS = {'project': 'REDACTED', 'datacenter': 'us-east1-b'}
```

@Eric Johnson:  Are you out there?  :)  Help!  This should be much simpler.  I'll draft a how to doc and send it to you for peer review if you help me get past this hump.  If it is good enough, maybe it can be posted online so other don't fight with this.  Maybe no one really cares enough and that is why I don't see enough answers to this problem.
Is there any debugging option I can turn on to get more info on these errors?
Who has this working?
Was http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html sufficient for you?
Do you agree the docs on getting this configured are a bit fragmented?